# Mi código no me deja crear librerías - C++

Tags: c++, c++11, dev-c++

Mi programa corre bien y todo, pero lo tengo solamente en un archivo `cpp`, quiero convertirlo a un proyecto y ahí poner mi clase creada para ya luego llamarla con `#include`, pero al momento de hacerlo me marca un error, no sé si es porque hay funciones antes de la clase (puesto que hay partes donde la clase llama a esas funciones) y otras funciones abajo de la clase (porque hay funciones que llaman a la clase creada).

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string>
#include<string.h>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<Windows.h>

#define Tecla_Arriba 72
#define Tecla_Abajo 80
#define Enter 13

using namespace std;

//funciones
void M_Prin(int _option, bool _band);
void M_SecRead(int _option2, bool _band2);
void VerifPositive();
void M_SecRemove(int _option2, bool _band2);
void VerifNegative();
void M_Scan();
void mayuscula(string& mayus);
void gotoxy(int x, int y);

//clases
class Libro {
private:
    string Titulo;
    string Autor;
    int Pagina;
    int Age;
    int Edicion;
    string ISBN;

public:
    Libro();//constructor predeterminado
    ~Libro();//destructor
    Libro(string, string, int, int, int);//constructor princopal
    Libro(string, string, int);

    void setTitulo(string);
    void setAutor(string);
    void setPagina(int);
    void setAge(int);
    void setEdicion(int);

    string getTitulo();
    string getAutor();
    int getPagina();
    int getAge();
    int getEdicion();

    void internalISBN();
    string getISBN();
    void mostrar();
};

Libro::Libro() {
}

Libro::~Libro() {

}

Libro::Libro(string _Titulo, string _Autor, int _Pagina, int _Age, int _Edicion) {
    mayuscula(_Titulo);
    Titulo = _Titulo;
    mayuscula(_Autor);
    Autor = _Autor;
    Pagina = _Pagina;
    Age = _Age;
    Edicion = _Edicion;
}
Libro::Libro(string _Titulo, string _Autor, int _Pagina) {
    mayuscula(_Titulo);
    Titulo = _Titulo;
    mayuscula(_Autor);
    Autor = _Autor;
    Pagina = _Pagina;
    Age = 0;
    Edicion = 0;
}

//setters
void Libro::setTitulo(string _Titulo) {
    mayuscula(_Titulo);
    Titulo = _Titulo;
}
void Libro::setAutor(string _Autor) {
    mayuscula(_Autor);
    Autor = _Autor;
}
void Libro::setPagina(int _Pagina) {
    Pagina = _Pagina;
}
void Libro::setAge(int _Age) {
    if (_Age == 0) {
        Age = 0;
    }
    else {
        Age = _Age;
    }
}
void Libro::setEdicion(int _Edicion) {
    if (_Edicion == 0) {
        Edicion = 0;
    }
    else {
        Edicion = _Edicion;
    }
}

//getters
string Libro::getTitulo() {
    return Titulo;
}
string Libro::getAutor() {
    return Autor;
}
int Libro::getPagina() {
    return Pagina;
}
int Libro::getAge() {
    return Age;
}
int Libro::getEdicion() {
    return Edicion;
}

//registrar ISBN
void Libro::internalISBN() {
    string subs1, subs2, _ISBN;
    std::string pag, ano, ed;

    subs1 = Titulo.substr(0, 2);
    subs2 = Autor.substr(0, 2);
    pag = std::to_string(Pagina);
    ano = std::to_string(Age);
    ed = std::to_string(Edicion);

    if (Age == 0) {
        if (Edicion == 0)
        {
            //cout<< subs2<<Pagina<<"0000"<<subs1<<"0E";
            ISBN = subs2 + pag + "0000" + subs1 + "0E";
        }
        else {
            ISBN = subs2 + pag + "0000" + subs1 + "0" + ed;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (Edicion == 0) {
            ISBN = subs2 + pag + ano + subs1 + "0E";
        }
        else {
            ISBN = subs2 + pag + ano + subs1 + "0" + ed;
        }
    }
}
string Libro::getISBN() {
    return ISBN;
}
//mostrar todos los datos de un fichero
void Libro::mostrar() {
    string nulo = "SIN DATO EXISTENTE";
    if (Age > 0) {
        if (Edicion > 0) {
            cout << "TITULO: " << Titulo << endl << "AUTOR: " << Autor << endl << "PAGINAS: " << Pagina << endl << "AÑO: " << Age << endl << "EDICION: " << Edicion << endl << "ISBN: " << ISBN << endl << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "TITULO: " << Titulo << endl << "AUTOR: " << Autor << endl << "PAGINAS: " << Pagina << endl << "AÑO: " << Age << endl << "EDICION: " << nulo << endl << "ISBN: " << ISBN << endl << endl;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (Edicion > 0) {
            cout << "TITULO: " << Titulo << endl << "AUTOR: " << Autor << endl << "PAGINAS: " << Pagina << endl << "AÑO: " << nulo << endl << "EDICION: " << Edicion << endl << "ISBN: " << ISBN << endl << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "TITULO: " << Titulo << endl << "AUTOR: " << Autor << endl << "PAGINAS: " << Pagina << endl << "AÑO: " << nulo << endl << "EDICION: " << nulo << endl << "ISBN: " << ISBN << endl << endl;
        }
    }
}

//funciones 
void ordenar(Libro* e, int tam);
void busqueda(Libro* e, string busq, int tam);

//variables universales
int a = 10;
Libro ejemplo[10];
int sumatoria;
//menu principal

int main() {
    //variables a necesitar
    int option = 1;
    bool band = true;

    //mostrar menu
    M_Prin(option, band);

    getch();
    return 0;
}

//funcion menu principal
void M_Prin(int _option, bool _band) {

    int opciones = 4;
    int OpcionSeleccionada = 1;
    int Tecla;

    while (_band == true) {
        system("color 0F");
        bool entr = true;

        do {
            system("cls");

            gotoxy(5, 4 + OpcionSeleccionada);
            cout << "==>";

            gotoxy(15, 2); cout << "****BIENVENIDO AL MENU PRINCIPAL BIBLOTECARIO****";
            gotoxy(10, 3); cout << "Que deseas hacer ";
            gotoxy(10, 5); cout << "1. - Ingresar Libro ";
            gotoxy(10, 6); cout << "2. - Eliminar Libro ";
            gotoxy(10, 7); cout << "3. - Buscar Libro ";
            gotoxy(10, 8); cout << "4. - Salir ";

            do {
                Tecla = getch();
            } while (Tecla != Tecla_Arriba && Tecla != Tecla_Abajo && Tecla != Enter);

            switch (Tecla) {
            case Tecla_Arriba:
                OpcionSeleccionada--;
                if (OpcionSeleccionada < 1) {
                    OpcionSeleccionada = opciones;
                }
                break;
            case Tecla_Abajo:
                OpcionSeleccionada++;
                if (OpcionSeleccionada > opciones) {
                    OpcionSeleccionada = 1;
                }
                break;
            case Enter:
                entr = false;
                break;
            }
        } while (entr == true);

        switch (OpcionSeleccionada) {
        case 1:
            M_SecRead(_option, _band);
            break;
        case 2:
            M_SecRemove(_option, _band);
            break;
        case 3:
            M_Scan();
            break;
        case 4:
            _band = false;
            system("cls");
            cout << endl << "\thasta pronto";
            break;
        }
    }
}
//ingreso de datos
void M_SecRead(int _option2, bool _band2) {
    system("color 0A");

    int opciones = 2;
    int OpcionSeleccionada = 1;
    int Tecla;

    while (_band2 == true) {
        bool entr = true;

        do {
            system("cls");

            gotoxy(5, 4 + OpcionSeleccionada);
            cout << "==>";

            gotoxy(15, 2); cout << "****BIENBENIDO AL MENU DE INGRESO DE LIBROS****";
            gotoxy(10, 3); cout << "Que Deseas Hacer ";
            gotoxy(10, 5); cout << "1.- Ingresar Libro ";
            gotoxy(10, 6); cout << "2. - Salir ";

            do {
                Tecla = getch();
            } while (Tecla != Tecla_Arriba && Tecla != Tecla_Abajo && Tecla != Enter);

            switch (Tecla) {
            case Tecla_Arriba:
                OpcionSeleccionada--;
                if (OpcionSeleccionada < 1) {
                    OpcionSeleccionada = opciones;
                }
                break;
            case Tecla_Abajo:
                OpcionSeleccionada++;
                if (OpcionSeleccionada > opciones) {
                    OpcionSeleccionada = 1;
                }
                break;
            case Enter:
                entr = false;
                break;
            }
        } while (entr == true);

        switch (OpcionSeleccionada) {
        case 1:
            VerifPositive();
            _band2 = false;
            break;
        case 2:
            _band2 = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
//sirve para que la consola pueda verificar si hay un numero o no dentro del indice del vector
void VerifPositive() {
    string _option3;

    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        string _ingresos_s, _ingresos_s2;
        int _ingresos_i, ingresos_extr;
        if (ejemplo[i].getTitulo() == "\0"/*esto significa null en formato string*/) {
            system("cls");
            cout << endl << "\tDigite la informacion libro-" << endl;

            cout << endl << "\tTitulo: ";
            cin.ignore();
            getline(cin, _ingresos_s);
            ejemplo[i].setTitulo(_ingresos_s);

            cout << endl << "\tAutor: ";
            cin.ignore();
            getline(cin, _ingresos_s2);
            ejemplo[i].setAutor(_ingresos_s2);

            cout << endl << "\tPaginas: ";
            cin >> _ingresos_i;
            cin.ignore();
            ejemplo[i].setPagina(_ingresos_i);

            cout << endl << "\tSi no tiene los datos de las casillas siguientes dejar en 0." << endl;
            cout << endl << "\tAño de salida: ";
            cin >> ingresos_extr;
            cin.ignore();
            if (ingresos_extr > 0) {
                ejemplo[i].setAge(ingresos_extr);
                ingresos_extr = 0;
            }
            else {
                ingresos_extr = 0;
            }
            cout << endl << "\tedicion: ";
            cin >> ingresos_extr;
            cin.ignore();
            if (ingresos_extr > 0) {
                ejemplo[i].setEdicion(ingresos_extr);
                ingresos_extr = 0;
            }
            else {
                ingresos_extr = 0;
            }

            ejemplo[i].internalISBN();

            system("cls");
            cout << endl << "\tSe almaceno:" << endl;
            ejemplo[i].mostrar();
            sumatoria++;

            ordenar(ejemplo, sumatoria);

            if ((i + 1) >= a) {
                cout << "\tA ingresado el maximo de numeros, favor de al menos eliminar alguno para continuar \n\tSe le regresara al menu principal\n\n";
                i = a;
            }
            else {
                cout << "\tDesea ingresar otra informacion? Si/No: ";

                cin >> _option3; cin.ignore();

                //  cin >> _option3;
                if (_option3 == "no" || _option3 == "NO" || _option3 == "No") {
                    i = a;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            if (ejemplo[a - 1].getTitulo() != "\0") {
                system("cls");
                cout << endl << "\tA ingresado el maximo de Libros, favor de al menos eliminar alguno para continuar \n\tSe le regresara al menu principal" << endl << endl;
                system("pause");
            }
        }
    }
}

//eliminacion de datos
void M_SecRemove(int _option2, bool _band2) {
    system("color 04");

    int opciones = 2;
    int OpcionSeleccionada = 1;
    int Tecla;

    while (_band2 == true) {
        bool entr = true;

        do {
            system("cls");

            gotoxy(5, 4 + OpcionSeleccionada);
            cout << "==>";

            gotoxy(15, 2); cout << "****BIENBENIDO AL MENU DE ELIMINACION DE DATOS****";
            gotoxy(10, 3); cout << "Que deseas hacer ";
            gotoxy(10, 5); cout << "1.-eliminar Libro ";
            gotoxy(10, 6); cout << "2. - salir ";

            do {
                Tecla = getch();
            } while (Tecla != Tecla_Arriba && Tecla != Tecla_Abajo && Tecla != Enter);

            switch (Tecla) {
            case Tecla_Arriba:
                OpcionSeleccionada--;
                if (OpcionSeleccionada < 1) {
                    OpcionSeleccionada = opciones;
                }
                break;
            case Tecla_Abajo:
                OpcionSeleccionada++;
                if (OpcionSeleccionada > opciones) {
                    OpcionSeleccionada = 1;
                }
                break;
            case Enter:
                entr = false;
                break;
            }
        } while (entr == true);

        switch (OpcionSeleccionada) {
        case 1:
            VerifNegative();
            _band2 = false;
            break;
        case 2:
            _band2 = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
void VerifNegative() {
    string _option4;
    string Delate;
    int contar = 0, DelPos;
    bool bandera = true;

    while (bandera == true) {
        system("cls");

        contar = 0;

        cout << endl << "\t\t-Sacando Lista de Libros-" << endl << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {               //Saca el libro hasta el numero de datos que se ingres�
            if (ejemplo[i].getTitulo() != "\0") {
                ejemplo[i].mostrar();
            }
        }
        //----------------------------------Eliminando datos del vector--------------------------------------------------------
        cout << endl << "\t Ingrese el Titulo del libro borrar: ";
        getline(cin, Delate);
        mayuscula(Delate);

        //Contando el numero de veces que se repite el numero deseado a borrar
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            if (ejemplo[i].getTitulo() == Delate || ejemplo[i].getTitulo().find(Delate) != string::npos) {
                contar++; //contando las veces que se repite el mismo numero a borrar
            }
        }
        //Bucle para sacar las posiciones donde se repite el dato a eliminar.
        if (contar > 1) { //si se repite mas de una vez, el proceso se hara hasta seleccionar el que se vaya a borrar
            system("cls");
            for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
                if (ejemplo[i].getTitulo() == Delate || ejemplo[i].getTitulo().find(Delate) != string::npos) {
                    if (ejemplo[i].getTitulo() != "\0") {
                        cout << endl << "\tLa palabra o Titulo " << Delate << " se repite en la posicion [" << i + 1 << "] como :" << endl << ejemplo[i].getTitulo();
                    }
                }
            }

            cout << "\tCual posicion desea eliminar?\t";
            cin >> DelPos;
            //ejemplo[DelPos].~Libro();
            sumatoria --;
            ejemplo[DelPos].setTitulo("\0");
            ejemplo[DelPos].setAutor("\0");
            ejemplo[DelPos].setPagina(0);
            ejemplo[DelPos].setAge(0);
            ejemplo[DelPos].setEdicion(0);
            ordenar(ejemplo, sumatoria);

        }
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) { //Bucle para la informacion no repetida que se va a borrar
                if (ejemplo[i].getTitulo() == Delate || ejemplo[i].getTitulo().find(Delate) != string::npos) {
                    //ejemplo[i].~Libro();
                    sumatoria --;
                    ejemplo[DelPos].setTitulo("\0");
                    ejemplo[DelPos].setAutor("\0");
                    ejemplo[DelPos].setPagina(0);
                    ejemplo[DelPos].setAge(0);
                    ejemplo[DelPos].setEdicion(0);
                    ordenar(ejemplo, sumatoria);
                }
            }
        }

        cout << "\n\n\t\t\t-Libreria Actualizado-\n\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {               //Saca el vector hasta el numero de datos que se ingres�
            if (ejemplo[i].getTitulo() != "\0") {
                ejemplo[i].mostrar();
            }
        }

        cout << endl << "\t Desea eliminar otro Libro?:\t";
        cin >> _option4; cin.ignore();

        if (_option4 == "no" || _option4 == "NO") {     //Cierra el Bucle Principal.
            bandera = false;
        }
        contar = 0;
    }
}
void M_Scan() {
    string ingreso;
    system("cls");

    cout << "\n\t******MENU DE BUSQUEDA******" << endl << endl;
    cout << "ingrese el titulo a buscar" << endl;
    getline(cin, ingreso);
    mayuscula(ingreso);

    busqueda(ejemplo, ingreso, a);
}

//funciones
void mayuscula(string& mayus) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mayus.length(); i++) {
        mayus[i] = towupper(mayus[i]);
    }
}
void ordenar(Libro* e, int tam) {
    int j, k, salto;
    Libro aux;

    salto = tam / 2;

    while (salto > 0) {
        for (int i = salto; i < tam; i++) {
            j = i - salto;

            while (j >= 0) {
                k = j + salto;

                if (e[j].getTitulo().compare(e[k].getTitulo()) < 0) {
                    j = -1;
                }
                else {
                    aux = e[j];
                    e[j] = e[k];
                    e[k] = aux;
                }
            }
        }
        salto /= 2;
    }
}
void busqueda(Libro* e, string busq, int tam) {
    int res = 0;
    mayuscula(busq);

    for (int i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
        if (e[i].getTitulo().find(busq) != string::npos) {
            e[i].mostrar();
            res = 1;
        }
        else {
            if (res == 0 && i == (tam - 1)) {
                cout << busq << " no encontrado..." << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    system("pause");
}
void gotoxy(int x, int y) {
    HANDLE hcon;
    hcon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD dwPos;
    dwPos.X = x;
    dwPos.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hcon, dwPos);
}
```

Ya intenté compilarlo en *Dev C++* y en *Visual Studio 2019* y aun así me aparecen los errores.

Comment: **¡ 616 líneas de código !** Creo que deberías consultar lo que es un [mcve].

Comment: lo se, pero tenia quemostrar mi codigo completo por si era error del codigo, perdon

Comment: Lo conveniente sería que mostraras los errores que te da al compilar, así no nos obligas a deducirlos del código ;-)